# What is the fastest car in Saints Row 4, and where can I find it?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I found an Attrazione in Salander, which has traditionally been fastest in previous games, but I don't like sinking upgrades money into a car unless it's for keeps. What car is fastest in *Saints Row IV* (before and after upgrades), and how can I get it? Is there any way to get stats on the car in-game?

Comment: why would you want to drive when you can *fly*? :P

Comment: I generally go with a Peacemaker - it's fast, and I can cruise down the road with the sirens on. But I am not sure if it's the fastest.

Comment: @Lyrion the novelty wears off quickly. A GTA clone without driving is just a bad shooter.

Comment: @kotekzot No it is not, it just gives you a better way to move around. Instead of following the streets you just go over the buildings, there are a few other games that have done this, like infamous and prototype. If I want to drive around and cause chaos ill eventually buy GTA V, if I want to feel like a superhero running around causing chaos and bitchslapping people with a giant tentacle. Then ill play SR4, in the beginning it was a gta clone, now it is a game in its own form.

Comment: I posted a question and answer here for fastest vehicles of all categories (includes planes and motorcycles): [What are the fastest vehicles, and where or how can I get them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146007/4797)

Answer (score 10):

The [Saints Row Wiki lists the vehicles in the game and sorts according to their maximum speeds](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/Vehicles_in_Saints_Row_IV#Statistics), categories, and other statistics.

From that source, the fastest cars are (info in parentheses are how to get them):

- 2-person capacity cars

  - Attrazione
  - Wraith ([Shaundi's "Under Pressure"](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/Side_Quests#Shaundi) side quest reward)
- 4-person capacity cars

  - Blade
  - Genkimobile ("The Kinzie Gambit" primary quest, "[All Hands on Deck](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/All_Hands_on_Deck)" mission reward)
  - Hammer
  - Infuego
  - Pacemaker

If there is no unlock or reward info listed, then that means that the cars are either randomly parked or driven by NPCs. The 'unlockitall' cheat and the [Additional Cheats](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/additional-cheats.3212/) mod (PC only) can also add many of those cars to your garage.

Comment: I find the Temptress handles a lot better while not being significantly slower than the Attrazione.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest vehicles in the game in no particular order are:

- the Wraith,
- an alien vehicle called the Void
- Attrazione

These three vehicle attain the highest speed in the game, with or without nitrous. But personally, I think using the Super Sprint is the fastest way to move around. :)

Answer (score -1):

Temptress for me, you'll eventually find it outside the 2 count