# What are the fastest vehicles, and where or how can I get them?

Tags: saints-row-iv

For the different vehicle categories, what are the fastest? And where or how can I get them?

Since fully upgrading a vehicle costs a lot of money, it would be nice to know which vehicles are the fastest, so I could focus all upgrades on that particular vehicle.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128279/what-is-the-fastest-car-in-saints-row-4-and-where-can-i-find-it

Comment: a down-voter here: I generally do not find questions asking for lists of things like this to be useful. Often they do not have an 'actual problem that needs solving'. In this case, I personally find your 'problem' lacking in value for a general audience.

Comment: @ColinD I see, and thanks for the comment. Do you play SR4? Because in the Saints Row series, fully upgrading a vehicle in your garage costs a lot of money. The problem that I'm trying to address in this question is knowing which vehicles are the fastest so you could focus on obtaining those vehicles and using your cash money on upgrading the fastest vehicles only.

Comment: Close voter(s) as duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/128279/4797): Not all vehicles are cars.  Vehicles include aircraft and motorcycles.

Comment: @galacticninja I played through SR3. The way I played I was never short on cash for car upgrades. They seemed useful, but I also never found myself using most of the vehicles I upgraded. I know that play styles are different and such so that aside, I might have chosen not to vote on this question had you provided an answer (or acknowledged its existence) to the question linked by spartacus. You are a high rep user and so my expectations for you are higher.

Comment: @ColinD That question asks about cars only. I asked about vehicles here (which should include aircraft and motorcycles). I included cars in the answer to completely answer the question. Do you mean I should also answer that question linked to as related by Spartacus? If so, then [done](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/146021/4797).

Comment: note I said related, not dupe...

Comment: I think this is a very useful question. No idea why people would downvote it when a [similar question for GTA 5](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143874/what-is-the-fastest-car-in-gta-5-and-where-can-i-find-it) was a roaring success.

Answer (score 4):

The [Saints Row Wiki lists the vehicles in the game and sorts according to their speeds and categories](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles_in_Saints_Row_IV). This data is [extracted from the game's files](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/minimauls-saints-row-iv-tools.3188/).

From that source, the fastest vehicles in different categories are (info in parentheses are where/how to get them*):

- Hover-type helicopter/plane hybrids

  - Chrome Void (reward for a Virus Collection target located at Sunset Park, Downtown)
  - F-69 VTOL (start a Co-op Cat and Mouse and store it once you have control)
  - Screaming Eagle (a reskinned/retextured VTOL; will be in your garage if you have the Commander-in-Chief Pack DLC)
  - Void (piloted by Zin if at 3-5 bars of Notoriety)
- Planes

  - AB Destroyer (Wesley Cutter International Airport, New Colvin)
  - Snipes 57 (Wesley Cutter International Airport, New Colvin)
- Helicopter

  - Oppressor (Wesley Cutter International Airport, New Colvin)
- 2-person capacity cars

  - Attrazione
  - Wraith (Shaundi's "Under Pressure" side quest reward)
- 4-person capacity cars

  - Blade
  - Genkimobile (Kinzie’s "Gambit" side-quest reward)
  - Hammer
  - Infuego
  - Pacemaker
- Motorycles / Bikes

  - Angry Tiger (reward for Asha’s "Training Day" side-quest)
  - Kaneda
  - Wireframe X2 Phantom (reward for Virus Collection target located at Bridgeport, Carver Island)
  - X-2 Phantom (Shaundi’s "Under Pressure" side quest reward, or grab one during a Virus Injection diversion where it could be driven by enemies)

If there is no unlock/reward info, then that means that the vehicles are either randomly parked or driven by NPCs. The 'unlockitall' cheat and the [Additional Cheats](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/additional-cheats.3212/) mod (PC only) can also add many of those vehicles to your garage.

---

<sup>Source: Personal in-game experience; some info are from the vehicles' respective [Saints Row Wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/) articles.</sup>

Comment: Note that *none* of those are faster than the Player moving at maxed out Super Sprint...

Comment: @Shadur With an *aircraft*, you don't have to bother with jumping and gliding (which will slow you down) to avoid obstacles. Also the VTOL / Screaming Eagle / Void is fast, even without upgrades. Do you have info for Super Sprint's speeds (so we could compare it with a VTOL or Void's speeds)?